# Correctly enqueue scripts and styles in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

This is a simple task but I fail :(

In a HTML template I would do in the head section:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/mdb.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and before the body closure tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.js"></script>
```

How do I enqueue above exact styles and JS in WP?

Yes, using enqueue_style and enqueue_script

But, unfortunately, when I try it, JS is not enqueued.
Always overwritten by bootstrap JS instead of the mdv.js

Can somebody give me a example, how above styles + scripts would be correctly enqueued in my functions.php?

I appreciate

Here a example code

```
function my_scripts() {


    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mdb.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/goldbootstrap.css', array(), '3.3.4', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '4.3.0', 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );





    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4' );
    wp_enqueue_script('mdb-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mdb.js' );


    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the functions you have tried to write...

Comment: I used default WordPress enqueue_style and enqueue_script, there is not much to say here. the question really is, how exact above scripts and styles would needed to be added to the WP functions.php. Anyway I add the code...

Answer (score 5):

Please try with below code maybe useful for you.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'google-styles','https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-css','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-min-css',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'mdb-css',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mdb.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mdb-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mdb.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Try it and let me know if any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the full path with using `get_template_directory_uri()`. So your header code needs to replace with below code. Then check.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/mdb.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/mdb.js"></script>
```