# Wordpress Permalink Displaying Home Page Content

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a question about an issue I am experiencing since I recently switched from GoDaddy's Linux hosting plan to their cPanel hosting plan.

When I go to my website, selfilmed.com/blog, I currently have all of my Permalink's set to basic.  My website, selfilmed.com (which has many links to blog articles) works properly, and so do the links within the blog itself.  However, links that come up on Google do not load correctly.  Instead of loading the link google has (http://selfilmed.com/blog/2017/01/2017-ata-show-firenock/), I see the content that is actually on selfilmed.com/index.php without any styles of course.

I am on WordPress 4.8.1, running PHP 7.1.7, and MySql 5.6.36.  It seems that everything is compatible.  I have read a lot of info suggesting updates to the .htaccess file, which I have tried, but to no avail.  It seems that my issue is slightly different than others, who are just having their pages redirect their main blog page.  Where as, my blog Permalinks are redirecting to my home page outside of the blog.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "*My website, selfilmed.com (which has many links to blog articles) works properly, and so do the links within the blog itself*" Actually they don't. I went to your blog and no matter what link I used (nav menu, category dropdown in your right col, or a link from a post title), it gave the same result. However in every case the URL is not changing in the location bar, which suggest it could be an issue with your theme files. If your theme is not set up correctly as @ProEvils showed below, then the site isn't going to work properly.

Comment: my apologies.  I changed a setting on my site per the suggestion of someone else on another site.  I set the links back to plain from "month and name".  So now the links work.  I can definitely look into the theme setup.  But this was a direct copy from one server with GoDaddy to another.  The only thing that changed was the version of PHP, MySQL, and the server.  All of my site files are identical to what they were.

Comment: I only suggested your theme because none of your links were working combined with the paths issue. As the non-existent links are showing your homepage, do you have a problem with your 404 page? Id suggest disabling your plugins and custom theme to see if it works without them - that might suggest where the issue could be.

Comment: I think the issue is with the theme or a plugin as fluffy suggested. Try switching on the default theme & disabling all plugins. Then change the URLs again to see if it works at that point. If it does, then your theme isn't coded correctly/not setup for other types of URLs. If it doesn't then... we'll have to dig further

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried to change the theme as well as disabling any plugins that we had running.  To no avail I'm afraid.  I did update the paths for my supporting files, so they have direct url's, so at least the site looks correct when it loads.  However, I'm still at a loss as to why the URL's are not displaying the correct page when clicking links in my blog.  Any other advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its impossible to know without seeing your code & setup. Did you check that your 404 page is set up properly? It looks like any 404 errors are being sent back to your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the link you provided, it would seem that your site assets aren't loading in correctly due to relative URLs.

For example, your site is trying to load the css via this URL: http://selfilmed.com/blog/2017/01/2017-ata-show-firenock/**css/main.min.css**

Your CSS/JS/IMG files aren't located there.

You should check how your CSS/JS/Images are loading in the theme's header file. To fix this, use **absolute paths** like `http://selfilmed.com/css/main.min.css` for the URL instead of **relative paths** `/css/main.min.css`

Here is an example of each type on your site. This is why your fonts load in correctly, but not everything else.

I would advise you to also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656574/correctly-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-in-wordpress) question.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not entirely what I'm after.  I know that the CSS/JS files, etc, are not in the proper directory for that page.  But what I'm concerned with is that when you click on the link for http://selfilmed.com/blog/2017/01/2017-ata-show-firenock/, it is not showing that article at all.  It is showing me the content of the home page.